# jQuery Validate, submit on invalid handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

On a multipage form I'm using jQuery validate to allow the user to continue working on their form, or move forward without saving.

So, I want to literally just figure out if errors are present, show a dialog, and a yes/no to allow them to continue.  SubmitHandler only works when its correct, invalid when its broken, and I need to use the invalidHandler.  Though, when I try to break through the recursion issue with jquery validate, it tells me:

**`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'submit'`**

```
$('.form-submit-next').click(function() {
    $('#form').validate({ 
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    resizable : false,
                    width : 350,
                    height : 200,
                    modal : true,
                    buttons : {
                        "Yes" : function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            form.submit(); //errors here
                        },
                        "No": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }

    });
})
```

Comment: If you console.log(form), does it output the expected value? If not, you may want to assign it to a variable earlier in the logic. var form_submit_next = $('form-submit-next');

Comment: Oops. I referenced the wrong form in my example. I'm sure you know what I meant though.

Comment: No it's passing the event, instead of the form. submitHandler passes the correct item.

Comment: whatever, I just removed the required class on the inputs so it will submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a DOM submit when you click the 'yes' button which will bypass the validator:

```
buttons : {
   "Yes" : function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
       $(this)[0].submit();
   }
```